# Get the id of selected option of select tag in symfony2 controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form with only one select tag. I want to get the id of the selected option tag in my controller when a user submit the form. My form is

```
 <div class="one_third">
        <form name="portfolios" action="{{ path('MunichInnovationGroupBundle_portfolio') }}" method="post" >
            <h2>Select your portfolio</h2>
            <p>Change the portfolio to be managed:<br />
                <select name="portfolio" style="width: 265px; height:28px;">
                    <option selected="selected" value="default">Switch Your Portfolio</option>
                    {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
                        <option id={{ portfolio.id }}>{{ portfolio.portfolioName }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input style="margin-left:100px; height:26px; cursor:pointer; background-color: #2D9AD3 !important; border: 1px solid #067EBD; color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #067EBD;" type="submit"class="button2 tooltip" value="Switch">
            </p> 
        </form>
    </div>
```

In my controller

```
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $data = $request->request->all();
        //$portfolio_id = $data['portfolio_id'];
        var_dump($data);
        echo $data;
        exit();
    }
```

the var_dump($data) gives me something like this

```
array
 'portfolio' => string 'Umair Portfolio 1' (length=17)

Array
```

How can I get the id ?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change attribute id to the value

```
<option value={{ portfolio.id }}>{{ portfolio.portfolioName }}</option>
```

Comment: Did you try the above code? That would've been exactly what I'd recommend, the option tag must have **value** instead of **id** as attribute.

Comment: if you want to send the value of id in <select> you need to set the id in the value attribute

Comment: sorry i was very quick to comment ... that worked for me thanks :)